# What is the difference between as.character() and as( ,"character") in R

Tags: r

In the surface they both seem to be doing the same thing. But it seems to be the case that the latter `as(,"character")` is more powerful.

As an example consider the following:

```
library(rvest)

temp <- html("http://www.example.com/")
temp <- temp %>% html_node("div p")

str(temp)
#Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr> 

as.character(temp) 
#Error in as.vector(x, "character") 
#   cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'
```

Whereas `as(temp, "character")` gives

```
#[1] "<p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`as.character()` is an S3 generic, whereas `as()` is a function defined in the methods package for S4 generics and methods.

The author of an S3 class has no reason to write an S4 coercion method, so for intance

```
> as.data.frame(matrix(integer()))
[1] V1
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

but

```
> as(matrix(integer()), "data.frame")
Error in as(matrix(), "data.frame") : 
  no method or default for coercing "matrix" to "data.frame"
```

For S4 classes, one (i.e., the package developer) can (and really should) write both S3 and S4 methods for coercion of particular classes; a common paradigm is

```
as.character.MyClass <- function(x, ...) {}
setAs("MyClass", "character",
      function(from) as.character.MyClass(from))
```

In your example, the author (of XML) has provided a setAs function without the S3 equivalent, so you get special treatment using `as()`, but default (i.e., error) when using `as.character()`.

There is no general rule about which is 'more powerful'; it would not be at all surprising to find examples even in base R and the methods package where as.X and as(, "X") behave differently and even in a logically inconsistent way.

In the next release of R (3.2.0) you will be able to say

```
> methods(class=class(temp))
[1] [[          coerce      html_form   html_node   html_nodes  html_table 
[7] initialize  show        slotsFromS3
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

where 'coerce' is an indication that there is an S4 method for `as(temp, ...")`. The actual methods are

```
> x = methods(class=class(temp))
There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> attr(x, "info")
                                                  visible from     generic isS4
coerce,oldClass,S3-method                            TRUE           coerce TRUE
coerce,XMLAbstractDocument,XMLAbstractNode-method    TRUE  XML      coerce TRUE
coerce,XMLDocument,XMLInternalDocument-method        TRUE  XML      coerce TRUE
coerce,XMLInternalDocument,character-method          TRUE  XML      coerce TRUE
coerce,XMLInternalDocument,XMLHashTree-method        TRUE  XML      coerce TRUE
coerce,XMLInternalDocument,XMLInternalNode-method    TRUE  XML      coerce TRUE
coerce,XMLInternalNode,XMLInternalDocument-method    TRUE  XML      coerce TRUE
initialize,oldClass-method                           TRUE       initialize TRUE
show,oldClass-method                                 TRUE             show TRUE
slotsFromS3,oldClass-method                          TRUE      slotsFromS3 TRUE
```

On the other hand there is

```
> methods(class="matrix")
 [1] anyDuplicated as.data.frame as.raster     boxplot       coerce       
 [6] determinant   duplicated    edit          head          initialize   
[11] isSymmetric   Math          Math2         Ops           relist       
[16] subset        summary       tail          unique       
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

where we see methods `as.data.frame()` and `as.raster()` available for coercing a matrix.

Comment: Thanks you. A lot to take in, in one go for me. I need to look into S3 and S4 classes.